# Effective way to attach hangables to brick veneer wall?

Tags: hanging, veneer

So awhile back I made a wall with brick veneer for a fake, lighter weight "brick wall" look:

[Veneer Link](https://www.menards.com/main/flooring-rugs/tile-stone/quarry-tile/versatile-reg-2-3-4-x-7-5-8-tumbled-thin-brick-veneer-for-floors-and-walls/p-1444436120817-c-6560.htm?tid=-4094376965180368286&ipos=18)

I have been trying to find effective ways to hang things from it such as picture frames, a theremostat, etc. I do not want to use screws or drill holes as the items may move in the future. I would rather use something semi permanent.

- I have tried using the Command Hooks (removable hangers) but they just fall off since it doesn't stick to the veneer very well.
- I have also tried using hot glue which I thought would be a slam dunk but the same thing, the items just fall off the wall easily.

Any other suggestions? Perhaps something exists out there that I am unaware of?

Comment: they make special clips that attach to bricks. very effective from what i've seen; my g'ma used to have heavy ornate mirrors hanging with them. they look kind of like tiny rakes, but i don't know a brand to search for... if the brick facade is too planer, you might try a water-soluble adhesive like craft glue that can permeate the bricks and be steam-removed later; hotglue gets too thick too quickly to "soak in" to the brick's crevices. gluing washers or nuts let you use magnets or screws to attach items to the glue.

Comment: @dandavis I will try that this week. I think the water soluble adhesive will be the best bet. I have seen the hooks that attach but my grout is about even to the bricks so not much surface to grip onto.